# How to open multiple excel files with win32com?

Tags: python, excel, win32com

Is there a way to simplify this with same kind with `os.walk` or `glob`?

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

inputwb1 = "D:/apera/Workspace/Sounding/sounding001.xlsx"
inputwb2 = "D:/apera/Workspace/Sounding/sounding002.xlsx"

Sheet = 'OUTPUT'
excel = Dispatch("Excel.Application")

source = excel.Workbooks.Open(inputwb1)
source.Worksheets(Sheet).Range('F1:H500').Copy()
source.Worksheets(Sheet).Range('I1:K500').PasteSpecial(Paste=-4163)

source = excel.Workbooks.Open(inputwb2)
source.Worksheets(Sheet).Range('F1:H500').Copy()
source.Worksheets(Sheet).Range('I1:K500').PasteSpecial(Paste=-4163)
```

because this thing will take so much space if I want to write hundreds of it.

Comment: Side note: you want to call `Sheet` `SHEET`, instead, since it is a (global) constant. This is in accordance with PEP 8. When I see `Sheet`, I believe that `Sheet` is a class, which it is not, so this is confusing, in general. Following standard convention makes your code more legible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have almost answered your own question. Something like this might do it:

```
import glob
from win32com.client import Dispatch

Sheet = 'OUTPUT'
excel = Dispatch("Excel.Application")

for filename in glob.glob("D:/apera/Workspace/Sounding/sounding*.xlsx"):
    source = excel.Workbooks.Open(filename)
    source.Worksheets(Sheet).Range('F1:H500').Copy()
    source.Worksheets(Sheet).Range('I1:K500').PasteSpecial(Paste=-4163)
```

Comment: @EOL: I rolled back your change because: A. It has nothing to do with the question, and B. The OP did have the variable name title capitalized which may have meant something similar to what ALL CAPS does in PEP8.

Comment: I will not put my change back, then. However, I suggest that you consider reimplementing my change: I strongly disfavor giving answers that are arguably *not* examples of good style, as they reinforce bad practices. Here, using `Sheet` instead of `SHEET` violates PEP 8 for no good reason (`Sheet` indicates a class). Furthermore, following good practices in your answer would still be to the point, since you obviously answer the question, which is about `glob`.

Comment: #EOL: Well, I think such comparatively minor things are better left to comments, especially considering the other PEP8 naming violations there appear to be in the snippet (in things that may be completely out of the OP's control and/or are following a different set of guidelines, such as those MS Office's API may follow).

Answer (score 1):

you can open multiple excel files like this (example) :

```
import win32com.client
import os
path = ('D:\\New Folder\\MyExcelFiles\\')
fileslist = os.listdir('D:\\New Folder\\MyExcelFiles\\')
xl = win32com.client.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
xl.Visible = True

for i in fileslist :
xl.Workbooks.Open(path+i)
if xl.Cells.Find('2014'):
   xl.Cells.Replace('2015')
   xl.Save()
   xl.Workbooks.Close()
else:
   xl.Workbooks.Close()
```